# Is it possible to hide a Perspective with XMLA in Analysis Services 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SSAS cube that has 2 perspectives.
The second perspective is only used in a secured environment.
I would like this perspective to be hidden when new users connect to the general populations cube.
I know there is a way to create new perspectives using XMLA, but is there a way to hide an existing perspective with an XMLA script?

So far I have not been able to find anything about doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way a perspective can be hidden as it is just a subcube with no independent security.